# Proving that a piecewise function is Darboux integrable on $[0,2]$ assistance

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-sum

Let $f:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$f(x) =  \left\{
       \begin{array}\
        10,\quad \ 0\leq x < 1, \\ 
       100,\quad \ x = 1, \\
       -5,\quad \ 1 < x \leq 2. \\
      \end{array}  \right.
$$

Prove that $f$ is Darboux integrable and compute $\int_{0}^{2}f$.

**Attempt**

That the function is Darboux integrable means for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[0,2]$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$.

Suppose $P = \{t_{0}, \dots, t_{n}\}$ is a partition of $[0,2]$ with $t_{j-1} < 1 < t_{j}$.

For, $t_{0} < \dots < t_{j-1}$: $m_{i} = M_{i} = 10$

Also for $t_{j} < \dots < t_{n}$: $m_{i} = M_{i} = -5$

Now I'm having trouble with managing $x = 1$ which is where the discontinuity is and obviously the challenge of the problem.  At first I was going to say that $m_{i} = M_{i} = 100$ whichever interval the number 1 is in and that would give me:

$$L(f,P) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}m_{i}(t_{i} - t_{i - 1}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{j-1}10(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) + 100(t_{j} - t_{j-1}) + \sum_{j+1}^{n}-5(t_{i} - t_{i-1})$$

and

$$U(f,P) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}M_{i}(t_{i} - t_{i - 1}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{j-1}10(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) + 100(t_{j} - t_{j-1}) + \sum_{j+1}^{n}-5(t_{i} - t_{i-1})$$

Then subtracting these I would get $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = 0 < \epsilon$.

But I feel this isn't the right answer and I need to express the partition a bit more explicitly. Also whatever $U(f,P) - L(f,P)$ is, it is going to eventually converge to what the integral is. And when calculating the integral (as a check using earlier calc techinques) I get $5$ which is not the value of the difference in the upper and lower sums. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: just a comment. if $[t_{j-1}, t_j]$ is the interval that contains one, with $t_j-1 < 1 < t_j$ , then $M_j = 100$ and $m_j = -5$, thats because the interval will have elements belonging to $[1,2]$

Comment: Also. see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857961/changing-one-point-does-not-change-the-riemann-integral

Comment: U and L converge to what the integral is, not U-L, which converges to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed $\varepsilon$ and taken $\delta$ small enough, you can take
$$
t_{j-1}=1-\delta,\qquad t_j=1+\delta,
$$
so that
\begin{align}
L(f,P) &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}m_{i}(t_{i} - t_{i - 1}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{j-1}10(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) + \mathbf{(-5)}(t_{j} - t_{j-1}) + \sum_{j+1}^{n}(-5)(t_{i} - t_{i-1})=\\
&=10(1-\delta)-5\cdot2\delta-5(1-\delta)=5-15\delta\\
U(f,P) &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}M_{i}(t_{i} - t_{i - 1}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{j-1}10(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) + 100(t_{j} - t_{j-1}) + \sum_{j+1}^{n}(-5)(t_{i} - t_{i-1})=\\
&=10(1-\delta)+100\cdot2\delta-5(1-\delta)=5+195\delta
\end{align}
so that to have
$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=210\delta<\varepsilon
$$
you have to choose
$$
\delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{180}.
$$

Comment: Hi. I was trying to figure out how you got the line $10(1-\delta)-5\cdot2\delta-5(1-\delta)=5-15\delta$. I was working it out and I see that it is supposed to be a telescoping sum of sorts, but I end up with the following if I'm doing it right:  $10(1+\delta - (1-\delta)) + (-5)((1+\delta - (1-\delta)) + (-5)(1+\delta - (1-\delta))$

Comment: No telescoping, The first sum gives $m_i=10$ times the complessive amplitude of the left intervals, i.e. $1-\delta$, the second the minimum, i.e. $-5$ times the amplitude of the central interval, i.e. $2\delta$, the third $m_i=-5$ times the complessive amplitude of the right intervals, i.e. $1-\delta$

Comment: I see, but wouldn't the interval be $t_{i} - t_{i-1} = ((1+\delta) - (1- \delta))$ ? That seems to be where my misunderstanding is

Comment: @dc3rd yes, $t_j-t_{j-1}=(1+\delta)-(1-\delta)=2\delta$, for the central interval, but $$\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(t_i-t_{i-1})=t_{j-1}-t_1=(1-\delta)-0=1-\delta.$$ Similarly on the righ you have $2-(1+\delta)=1-\delta$

Comment: Oh...so you used the idea of the partition $P$, but only needed to use the end points, to establish those other intervals.....Beautiful. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Actually 2 quick things: 1) I think it is supposed to be $U(f,P)-L(f,P)= 210\delta<\varepsilon$. and 2). To calculate the result, since I can make the $\delta$ as small as possible, would the answer be 5? I say this because I'm imagining a $\delta$ so small it is almost $0$.

Comment: @dc3rd Yes you're right on both, corrected